# When is a field "compatible" with an abelian group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $G$ an abelian group. We say that $F$ and $G$ are "compatible" if and only if there exists a function $M:F\times G\to G$ such that

1. $M(\lambda,gh)=M(\lambda,g)M(\lambda,h)$ for all $\lambda\in F$, $g,h\in G$
2. $M(\lambda+\mu,g)=M(\lambda,g)M(\mu,g)$ for all $\lambda,\mu\in F$, $g\in G$
3. $M(\lambda\mu,g)=M(\lambda,M(\mu,g))$ for all $\lambda,\mu\in F$, $g\in G$
4. $M(1,g)=g$ for all $g\in G$
5. $M(0,g)=\varepsilon$ for all $g\in G$, where $\varepsilon$ is the identity of $G$

If $F$ and $G$ are compatible, then $(F,G)$ (or $\{F,G,M\}$, or $\langle F,+_F,\cdot_F,G,+_g,M\rangle$, or however else you care to denote it) forms a vector space, whose field is $F$, whose vectors are $G$ with vector addition given by the group operation, and scalar multiplication given by $M$.

In fact, this is *the definition* of a vector space - a vector space consist precisely of a field and an abelian group related by a function like the one described.

**Question:** What methods can be used to efficiently decide the compatibility of a given field with an arbitrary abelian group?

There is a trivial case. If we take $F^X$ to be the group of functions from $X$ to $F$ with pointwise addition, and $G\cong F^X$, then $F$ and $G$ are compatible by $M(\lambda,\varphi^{-1}(g))(x)=\lambda \varphi^{-1}(g)(x)$, where $\varphi:F^X\to G$ is any group isomorphism. Every vector space for which I have a name is of this form, but, if I'm not mistaken, one can easily construct one which isn't by matching a group with an involution to a field whose additive group has none.

Comment: I find your question somewhat unclear. Are you thinking of a context in which you have computable representations of the algebraic structures and want a way of effectively computing whether the field is compatible with the group? If not, what do you mean by "efficiently"?

Comment: I find your question setup unnecessarily long: "when does $G$ admit an $F$-vector space structure?" would have been enough.

Comment: @CaptainLama, at some stage of the learning process, lengthness may not be a choice, but a necessity. From a higher standpoint it may look "unnecessary", but from the OP's one may not, or simply can't be avoided (yet).

Comment: @citadel: a good point, but in this case it reads as if the OP has introduced noise into the question on his or her own accord (the question states that this **is** the definition of a vector space, which is true, but only when you remove the noise).

Comment: Fair enough, @RobArthan

Comment: @citadel: Quite agreed, learning to be clear and concise takes time and experience.  But students learn that exactly through getting feedback like @CaptainLama’s comment.

Comment: Sure, @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, I just wanted to point out the relativity of the adverb "unnecessarily". Well noted, though.

Comment: To explicitly address your last paragraph: it's true that not every vector space is of the form $F^X$, but not because of the reasoning you give. Noah's answer says that every vector space *is* of the form "the subspace of $F^X$ of finitely supported functions". However, $F^X$ itself is always either finite-dimensional or uncountable-dimensional, while there are countable-dimensional vector spaces (eg the direct sum of $\aleph_0$ many copies of $F$, or "the space of polynomials over $F$").

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen That was misphrasing on my part - I should have said "is a *subspace* of a space of this form."  Mainly, I was assuming (incorrectly) that nontrivial quotients can form a vector space over the same field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What might be called the fundamental theorem of linear algebra - "Every vector space has a basis" - solves this problem quickly: if $V$ is a vector space over $k$, then $V$ as an abelian group is isomorphic to some direct sum of the additive group of $k$. Put another way:

> Suppose we have an abelian group $G$ and a field $k$. Then $G$ can be equipped with the structure of a $k$-vector space iff for some (possibly infinite) cardinal $\mu$ we have $G\cong \bigoplus_{i<\mu}k_+$, where $k_+$ is the additive group of $k$.

Note the direct sum rather than direct product here: the point is that if $B$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, each element of $V$ only "uses" finitely many elements of $B$.

Also, note that things are more interesting for modules (= just require that $k$ be a ring, not necessarily a field): for example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a  $\mathbb{Z}$-module in an obvious way despite not being a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the direct sum. How would one produce, for instance, the group of function $\Bbb R^\Bbb R$? I suppose it's something like $\mu=2^{\mathfrak c}$, abuse AC until the problem is solved? Additionally, what about the case where $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient of a product, or product of quotients? Isn't the circle group a vector space - albeit an unconventional one - over the reals under $M(\lambda,z)=z^\lambda$?

Comment: @R.Burton Re: your first question, yup: as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the $2^\mathfrak{c}$-fold direct sum of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself. Meanwhile the circle is *not* an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space since we can argue e.g. $${1\over 2}\cdot 0={1\over 2}\cdot (\pi+\pi)={1\over 2}\cdot\pi +{1\over 2}\cdot \pi=\pi\not=0$$ (thinking of the circle as $\mathbb{R}/2\pi$ for concreteness). There really are no other kinds of vector space!